# Как сделать плавное движение строки по Canvas?

Tags: java, многопоточность, gui

Я написал отдельный класс потока, в котором двигаю строку по канвасу. И проблема в том, что если я делаю `.repaint()`, то большую часть времени строку вообще не видно, а если не делаю - строка остаётся на прошлом месте, и в итоге получается движущееся пятно. Как сделать адекватное передвижение строки по канвасу, используя поток?

```
class MyThreads extends Thread  {
    Authorization reglog;
    Graphics g;
    Dimension dim;
    SimpleWind s;

    public MyThreads(SimpleWind draw){
        g = draw.getGraphics();
        dim = draw.getSize();
        s = draw;
    }

    public void run(){
        String result = null;

        for(int i = 0;;i++){
            boolean resultOfAuthorization = reglog.getResultOfAuthorization();

            if (resultOfAuthorization) {
                result = "Succesfully entered";
            } else {
                result = "You are not entered yet.";
            }

            g.drawString(result, i, 50);
            s.repaint();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: какой именно фреймворк используете?

Comment: если свинг, то есть другие методы для переисовки, для этого нужно изучить конвейер свинг